# Symfony3 Hello World: Attempted to call an undefined method named "redirect"

Tags: symfony

I am getting started with Symfony 3 following the downloadable book. However I can't get past the basic Hello World function when using the Controller class to extend my index Action.

The error I receive is "Attempted to call an undefined method named "redirect" . I have followed the documentation successfully up to this point. It looks like my Hello Wrold app cannot reference the Symfony Controller Class.

The below works fine:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class HelloController
{
    /**
        * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello")
    */

    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Hello '.$name.'!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

But when I extend the index Controller by adding the below two lines as per the documentation I get the error "Attempted to call an undefined method named "redirect" of class "AppBundle\Controller\HelloController"."

I added these two lines, including the Symfnoy controller class and returning with a redirect.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
return $this->redirect('http://symfony.com/doc');
```

Comment: class HelloController extends Controller

Comment: Thanks Cerad, I completely missed that

Comment: Gregsands, you should upvote Cerad's comment if it was helpful. Thanks!